# Is the mixed strategy $\sigma_i^*:S_i\times\Theta\to\Delta(A_i)$ chosen by player $i$ linear?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game

Suppose that we have a Bayesian game, where

1. the number of players is $I$ and we refer to the generic player with $i$
2. $\Theta$ stands for the state of the world, where $\theta\in\Theta$ is the typical element of the state space. Also, $\psi$ is the common prior beliefs about the state of the world, such that $\psi\in\Delta_{++}(\Theta)$ (full support)
3. $S_1\times S_2\times\cdots\times S_I$ is the space of private signals, and $s\in S$ is the profile of state dependent signals that is drawn according to $\pi:\Theta\to\Delta(S)$ and every player $i$ will learn her own private signal $s_i$.
4. $A=\Pi_{i\in I}A_i$ is the compact space of pure strategies where $A_i$ is the strategy space of player $i$ and we further assume that $|A_1|=\cdots=|A_i|=|A_I|$, namely the strategy spaces are all of the same cardinality. Then the mixed strategy profile is $\sigma:S\times\Theta\to\Delta(A)$
5. The utility function is the continuous function $u_i:\Theta\times A\to\mathbb{R}$ for every player $i$ or $u=(u_i)_{i\in I}:\Theta\times A\to\mathbb{R}^I$ as an $I$ dimensional vector.

Suppose that the of profile mixed strategies that constitutes a Bayesian Nash equilibrium is an $I$-tuple $\sigma^*=(\sigma_1^*,\sigma_2^*,\cdots,\sigma_I^*)$ where every player $i$ choose the strategy $\sigma_i^*$, which is her best response strategy with respect to the best response strategies of the other players. Is the mixed strategy $\sigma_i^*$ chosen by player $i$ linear? Does this hold for every mixed strategy $\sigma_i\in\Sigma_i$?

For example take the case where we have $I=4$ and $|A_1|=\cdots=|A_i|=|A_I|=3$, namely every player's set of action contains three pure strategies.

Comment: You did not specify any vector space structure on $S_i$, but even if you would, there is no reason why strategies should be linear.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker so there must be some extra assumption that I need to make so as the strategies should be linear? If I am not mistaken the mixed-strategy space and the image of the best response correspondence are convex, aren't they? Could this be related with the linearity of the strategies somehow?

Comment: Yes, there is a natural linear structure on (a space containing the) space of mixed actions. Assumptions that guarantee linearity will be extremely strong. What do you need linearity for in the end?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Maybe I do not need it. I just wanted to make a connection with an older post https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/50935/i-present-a-communication-game-could-you-please-make-comments-on-my-assumption

but check this one there. I think I will write some thoughts as an answer...take a look in about 5 minutes...i will delete this post...